# I'm having trouble creating a generic Thread Class for connecting to different databases defined at run-time using C++ Builder 11.3

Tags: multithreading, database-connection, c++builder, firedac, tthread

The databases are created at run-time. The thread should be run every 15 minutes to query for new records in a given database. I've gotten it the point where the Thread seems to be working, but the TFDConnection keeps throwing a:

`Thread: [FireDAC][Comp][Clnt]-512. Connection is not defined for []. Possible reason: Connection and ConnectionName property values are both empty`

I tried to follow the Delphi example for Pooling, but Delphi doesn't exactly port well to C++.  So I did it the best way I know.  Here's are two code snippets for the Thread and the calling method.

```
__fastcall TDataHandlerThread::TDataHandlerThread(bool CreateSuspended, TFDPhysDriverLink *ADriverLink, 
                                                  TDataSource *DataSource, String AConnectionStr, 
                                                  String ACommandStr) : TThread(false)
{

    FreeOnTerminate = true;

    try {
        std::unique_ptr<TFDConnection>   FConnection    = std::make_unique<TFDConnection>(nullptr);
        std::unique_ptr<TFDEventAlerter> FAlerter       = std::make_unique<TFDEventAlerter>(nullptr);
                                         FQuery         = std::make_unique<TFDQuery>(nullptr);  
        FDataSource = DataSource;
    
        TFDPhysDriverLink   *DriverLink = ADriverLink;
        
        FAlerter->OnAlert = PgEventAlerterAlert;

        FAlerter->Options->Kind = "Notifies";
        FAlerter->Options->Synchronize = True;
        FAlerter->Options->Timeout = 10000;
        FAlerter->OnAlert = PgEventAlerterAlert;
        FAlerter->Active = True;
        FAlerter->Register();
        
        
        FConnection->ConnectionString = AConnectionStr;   // Prvate Connection String;
        FConnection->ConnectionName="PG";
        FConnection->Connected = true;

        FQuery->Connection = FConnection.get();
        FQuery->SQL->Text = ACommandStr;
        FDataSource->DataSet = FQuery.get();


    } catch (const Exception &exception) {
        AlertMainForm("Exception in Thread: " + exception.Message); 
        Terminate();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TDataHandlerThread::AlertMainForm(String str)
{
    TThread::Queue(NULL, [this, str]() -> void {    
        MainForm->Memo->Lines->Add("THREAD: " + str);
    });
}

TDataHandlerThread::~TDataHandlerThread()
{

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TDataHandlerThread::Execute()
{
        try
        {
//          while(!Terminated)
            if(!Terminated)
            {
                if(FQuery->Active) {
                    FQuery->Close();
                    FDataSource->Enabled=false;
                }

                FQuery->Open();
                FDataSource->Enabled=true;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(5));           
            }
        }
        catch(const Exception &exception)
        {
            AlertMainForm("THREAD: ERROR " + exception.Message);
        }
}
```

And  from the calling method:

```
void __fastcall TScheduler::DoExecute()
{
    try
    {
        String Pg_Connect_str  = "DriverID=PG;Server=XX.XXX.XX.XXX;Port=XXXXX;Database=XXXXX;User_Name=XXXXXX; \
                                    Password=----;CharacterSet=utf8;ExtendedMetadata=true;";

        String CmdStr = "select * from customers WHERE last_update_time > " + FormatDateTime( "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", FLastRetrievalTime ) + "'");;

        TDataHandlerThread *runner = new TDataHandlerThread(false, FDPhysPgDriverLink, dsJwareCustomers, Pg_Connect_str,  CmdStr);

    } catch (const Exception &exception) {
        MainForm->ExceptionThrown("Exc:[0x0A][Execute]:" + exception.Message );
    }
}
```

In the past, I've been able to drop a TFDConnection onto a DataModule for use with Postgres and set it up entirely in code, not assigning a ConnectionName nor a Driver, yet using the same technique here it is not getting the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating *and destroying* the `TFDConnection` object (and the `TFDEventAlerter` object) in your thread's constructor using local `unique_ptr` variables that go out of scope when the constructor exits.

Thus, the `TFDConnection` object won't exist anymore when the thread calls `Execute()` , so the `TFDQuery` object can't do its work. You can verify this by looking at the `FQuery->Connection` property inside of `Execute()` - it will have been reset back to null when the `TFDConnection` object is destroyed.

If you are going to create the objects in the thread's constructor, you need to get rid of the local `unique_ptr` variables. Make them members of the thread class instead, as you appear to have done for the `TFDQuery` object.

Otherwise, create all objects locally in `Execute()` instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you Remy, let me try that and see what happens.

Comment: So there were two issues, one was what you caught, the other was with the FDAlerter.  It failed on the Register method and/or setting the Active=true property.

Comment: Ran out of time.  So I moved the members to the header as you suggested, but then the EventAlerter kept throwing.  Not sure if it's due running in it's own thread and sync issues.  But I got rid of it and did your fix and yup, worked as it should've.  The EventAlerter is needed to flag events in PG so the server can compute other functions based on those events.  Do you know of a way to use the EventAlerter in a thread?  Or perhaps a better way to message from the Thread? Thank you for your help Remy.

Comment: @pjackson I'm not familiar with `TFDEventAlerter`, but just from the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC)) about it, it uses its own thread and connection.

Comment: Very well sir.  After giving it some thought I can simply use the TFDEventAlerter in another unit, it doesn't really matter "where" the messages from PG arrive, as long as they come in.  I've read the docs and about everywhere else and still I'm having a hard time with threading, but I'll get there.  Just like the I did way back when you helped me with Streaming Blobs...and showed me how to use Queue and ForceQueue!  Many thanks...

Comment: Just for anyone reading this post.  You cannot use an TFDEventAlerter the way I proposed in my earlier comment.   The FDEventAlerter has to be connected to the FDConnection it's listen for events from, which in this case is the Thread. So my proposal will not work.